# why is my algorithm returning stackoverflow exception?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I have to do an algorithm that fills a bi-dimensional array with random (between 0 and 2) numbers, the only condition is that I can have the same number 3 or more times horizontally and vertically.
For example

```
[0,0,1,2,1
 0,1,2,1,2
 1,2,0,1,0]
```

is ok

```
[0,0,0,2,1
 0,1,2,1,2
 1,2,0,1,0]
```

or

```
[0,0,1,2,1
 0,1,1,1,2
 1,2,1,1,0]
```

is wrong.

So here is my algorithm:

```
public class CandyHelper {

    private final int minimumChainLength = 3;
    private final int searchChainSize    = 3;

    public Candy[][] randomInit(int rowCount, int columnCount) {
        Candy[][] map = new Candy[rowCount][columnCount];
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; ++column) {
                // Fill square with random candy.
                Random rand = new Random();
                int value = rand.nextInt(3);
                Candy candy = new Candy();
                candy.setType(value);
                map[row][column] = candy;
            }
        }

        if (findHint(map)) {
            //System.out.println("Winning conditions");
            map = null;
            map = randomInit(rowCount, columnCount);          
        } else {
            System.out.println("no wining");
        }

        return map;
    }

    // Function which searches for match of at least `MinimumChainLength`.
    private boolean findHint(Candy[][] map) {
        int rowCount = map.length;
        int columnCount = map.length;

        List<Candy> hintMove = new ArrayList<Candy>();

        // Search rows.
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row) {
            // Search for chain.
            for (int chainStart = 0; chainStart < columnCount - searchChainSize; ++chainStart) {
                // Add initial cell in chain.
                hintMove.clear();
                hintMove.add(map[row][chainStart]);
                for (int nextInChain = chainStart + 1; nextInChain < columnCount; ++nextInChain) {
                    if (map[row][nextInChain].getType() == hintMove.get(0).getType()) {
                        hintMove.add(map[row][nextInChain]);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }           
                // Was a chain found?
                if (hintMove.size() >= minimumChainLength)
                    return true;
            }
        }

        // Search columns.
        for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; ++column) {
            // Search for chain.
            for (int chainStart = 0; chainStart < rowCount - searchChainSize; ++chainStart) {
                // Add initial cell in chain.
                hintMove.clear();
                hintMove.add(map[chainStart][column]);
                for (int nextInChain = chainStart + 1; nextInChain < rowCount; ++nextInChain) {
                    if (map[nextInChain][column].getType() == hintMove.get(0).getType()) {
                        hintMove.add(map[nextInChain][column]);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Was a chain found?
                if (hintMove.size() >= minimumChainLength)
                    return true;
            }
        }

        // No chain was found, so clear hint.
        hintMove.clear();
        return false;     
    }

}
```

and my pojo:

```
public class Candy {
   private int type;

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Candy{" + "type=" + type + '}';
    }

}
```

When I start from an array of 10x10 I start getting the stack overflow errors.
What should I do to correct them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the whole stack trace

Comment: Stack overflow would make me look for a method that called itself again and again, adding more frames to the stack until it was exhausted.  Look for that.  (PS - "Candy"?  Is this meaningful for your context?)

Comment: Not the problem, but you don't want to be creating a new `Random` for each number you generate.

Comment: "the only condition is that I can have the same number 3 or more times horizontally and vertically." - that doesn't sound like a condition.

Comment: Firslty I presume you mean **can not** have same number 3 or more times horizontally and vertically, in that case your second matrix should not be ok since it has three zeros horizontally in the first line.

Comment: If you are getting stack overflow - most likely culprit is the recursive call made in randomInit.  I will see if I can recreate the issue using your sample code

Answer (score 1):

your problem is this line:

```
map = randomInit(rowCount, columnCount);
```

essentially every time findHint returns true you're going to recursively invoke randomInit. This means that the bigger the probability of FindHint returning true the higher the chance of a stackoverflow.  In your case the bigger you make your grid the higher the probability FindHint is going to return true and I guess at size 10 it's almost certain to end up in a stackoverflow.

I all honesty I'm not sure why you call randomInit again here rather than just returning the map?

Comment: I do that call to avoid having repeated columns and rows with 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

Without having run your code, I would guess that it has to do with `randomInit()` calling itself if `findHint()` is true. I can find nothing wrong with your code for `findHint()` (aside from a few performance tweaks - e.g. there's no need for you to construct a list of matches just to count how many there are), but the fact that you presumably only run into this problem on 10x10 grids is telling. Any 10x10 grid of objects with only three types is very likely to have three in a row - likely enough that it will cause your `randomInit()` to call itself enough times to get you your stack overflow.

I'm not 100% sure what you want `randomInit()` to do. If you want it to keep generating a random grid until there are no sets of N, I would suggest putting the grid generation code in a separate method (call it `generate()`) and then have `randomInit()` call it in a while loop:

```
boolean setFound;
do {
    map = generate(rowCount, columnCount);
    setFound = findHint(map);
} while (setFound);
```